# Service implements multiple ServiceContract types then Restful Service throws ServiceActivationException

Tags: wcf, rest, autofac

So, due to some concerns, I've split up what was initially a single interface contract into two separate ones. Now, I have only one class (partial) implementing both interfaces, and I want to make them all available as REST-services through WCF. The contracts are listed below.

I am using Autofac for WCF service host.

Below is my .svc file code

For WCF service: `Factory="Autofac.Integration.Wcf.AutofacServiceHostFactory, Autofac.Integration.Wcf"`

For RESTful service: `Factory="Autofac.Integration.Wcf.AutofacWebServiceHostFactory, Autofac.Integration.Wcf"`

**WCF Example**:

For wcf service

```
public interface IEmployeeCommandService {}
public interface IEmployeeQueryService {}
public partial class EmployeeService : IEmployeeCommandService {}
public partial class EmployeeService : IEmployeeQueryService {}
public partial class EmployeeService {}
```

And my Web.config file looks like below

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="Application.EmployeeService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Application.IEmployeeCommandService" />
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Application.IEmployeeQueryService" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
</service>
```

And my **EmployeeService.svc** code looks like

```
<%@ ServiceHost Service="Application.EmployeeService, Application"
Factory="Autofac.Integration.Wcf.AutofacServiceHostFactory, Autofac.Integration.Wcf"%>
```

with this approach the plain WCF service working fine for me. When browse the **EmployeeService.svc** I can see both command & Query service operations.

Simillar approach I am trying for RESTFul service as mentioned like below. But I am getting error when I browse my RESTFul service.

**RESTFul Example**:

```
public interface IEmployeeRESTfulQueryService {}
public interface IEmployeeRESTfulCommandService {}
public partial class EmployeeRESTfulService {}
public partial class EmployeeRESTfulService : IEmployeeRESTfulCommandService {}
public partial class EmployeeRESTfulService : IEmployeeRESTfulQueryService {}
```

And My web.confing looks like below

```
  <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="Application.EmployeeRESTfulService">
    <endpoint name="Command" address="Command" behaviorConfiguration="webHttp" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Application.IEmployeeRESTfulCommandService" />
    <endpoint name="Query" address="Query" behaviorConfiguration="webHttp" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Application.IEmployeeRESTfulQueryService" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>

<behavior name="webHttp">
 <webHttp helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled ="true" />
</behavior>
```

If I browse my .svc (RESTFul) I endup with below error..

**Error**:

Service 'EmployeeRESTfulService' implements multiple ServiceContract types, and no endpoints are defined in the configuration file. WebServiceHost can set up default endpoints, but only if the service implements only a single ServiceContract. Either change the service to only implement a single ServiceContract, or else define endpoints for the service explicitly in the configuration file..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Do you use the `Factory=System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory` on the .svc file? If so, remove the Factory attribute, since you're defining the endpoints in config.
2. An endpoint in WCF is bound to a contract (interface); if you have two different interfaces, you'll need two different endpoints.

*Update following edit*: the `Factory` used by the restful service, `Autofac.Integration.Wcf.AutofacWebServiceHostFactory, Autofac.Integration.Wcf`, is using the `WebServiceHost`, which requires the service class to implement only one `[ServiceContract]` interface. Do you need the Autofac factory? If not, just remove that attribute; otherwise, since you're already defining the endpoints via config, I imagine it should work with the "normal" factory (AutofacServiceHostFactory) as well (I've never used Autofac, but you can try that).